# How to directly change a vector3

Tags: unity, c#

I'm new to unity, and written code in general, but I haven't been able to change the value of a vector3.

```
public Vector3 VARIABLE = (5f, 5f, 5f)
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-x.html

Comment: I suspect that this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Changing a vectors x, y and z components should be trivial for anyone who has written "code in general", but you might do it in a situation where it won't do anything to change a specific vector. So you believe you are doing the vector manipulation wrong when what you actually should be doing is something else entirely. Please tell us what you actually want to achieve and the code you wrote to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to write

```
public Vector3 variable = new Vector3(5f, 5f, 5f);
```

like this instead? The `new Vector3` constructor is necessary - the C# compiler doesn't know where to stick each `5f` inside the data structure without it. Don't worry, since this is a struct, that `new` doesn't perform extra allocation or generate garbage: the memory for this vector is already accounted-for in its parent type's footprint.

Another common error in Unity is to write something like this:

```
transform.position.x = 5f;
```

This again is because vectors are structs - value types. So `transform.position` give you a *copy* of the variable inside the transform. To change just one component of a vector inside another instance, you have to take a copy, change it, and assign it back as a whole:

```
var modifiedPosition = transform.position;
modifiedPosition.x = 5f;
transform.position = modifiedPosition;
```

Since vectors are blittable types (able to be moved around as just a raw byte-for-byte copy), this is super fast, so you shouldn't worry that those three lines are somehow going to make your code slow.

If you want to increment a vector, there are often convenience methods that let you do this a bit more easily. Say we want to *add* 5 to `x` instead of *setting* it to 5. We can do that with a one-liner:

```
transform.Translate(5f, 0f, 0f, Space.World);
```